# System of equations. Solve for x and y.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If from twice the greater of two numbers 17 is subtracted, the result is half the other number. If from half the greater number 1 is subtracted, the result is two-thirds of the smaller number.

$$2x - 17 = \frac{ 1 }{2}y$$

$$\frac{ x }{2} - 1 = \frac{ 2 }{3}y$$

$$-17 - 4 = \frac{ 1 }{2}y - \frac{ 8 }{3}y$$

I'm so, off. I need a little help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Half** of the greater number, this means $\frac{x}{2}$ in the second equation, rest seems all right!

Now, if you multiply the lower equation by $4$ and subtract it from the first, you get:
$$-13=\frac{y}{2}-\frac{8y}{3}$$
$$\implies y=6$$  you can find that $$x=10$$

Comment: How did you turn the x into y?

Comment: @W.Zlacki sorry?

Comment: For $$\frac{ x }{2}$$ you put $$\frac{ y }{2}$$ Look what I originally put at the top.

Comment: Did you read what I have written, I multiplied the second equation by 4 and then subtracted it from the first one; This cancels out $x$ altogether

Comment: I get that now. I'm still stuck on y.

Comment: Just a little more help.

Comment: Multiply both sides by $6$ to the equation $-13=\frac{y}{2}-\frac{8y}{3}$

Comment: I was multiplying in fractions. I think I finally learned that part. Thank you.

Comment: Glad you got it!

Comment: Y comes out to 5.99999..., I had to do this problem all over.

Answer (score 4):

**Basic approach.** Your equations look right to me, except that it should be $x/2$ in the second equation, not $x$.

Now, if you multiply both sides of the upper equation by $2$, and both sides of the lower equation by $3$, you will get two expressions for $y$ in terms of $x$ that can be equated with each other.  Using them, you can determine the value of $x$, and from that, determine the value of $y$.

Answer (score 1):

#### This can be solved using substitution

Here's a step by step solution:

1. Solve for x in the first equation, 
   $x=\frac{17}{2}+\frac{y}{4}$
2. Replace all occurrences of x in the second equation,
   $\frac{\left(\frac{17}{2}+\frac{y}{4}\right)}{2}-1=\frac{2y}{3}$
3. Solve for y,
   $y=6$
4. Take the solution for x and replace y with 6,
   $x=\frac{17}{2}+\frac{6}{4}$
5. Solve,
   $x=10$

---

**Answer**

$y=6$
$x=10$

Comment: You lost me with the 4.

Comment: @W.Zlacki When you solve for x in the first equation, we get $x=\frac{17}{2}+\frac{y}{4}$